# Selenium how to get value between tags

Tags: python

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp950' codec can't encode character '\u2764' in position 2: illegal multibyte sequence
```

I want to get the word 'SOHO yaya'

It's the web

```
<h1 class="nowrap" style="font-size: 1.8em;line-height:36px;margin:0.5em 0.4em;">
SOHO yaya
    <span style="font-size:12pt;color:gray;">#B59360</span>

    <div class="types-nav row mtn" style="padding-left:0;">
          ...
          ...
    </div>

</h1>
```

This's my code

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//h1[@class="nowrap"]')
```

And the error was

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp950' codec can't encode character '\u2764' in position 2: illegal multibyte sequence
```

How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're running Python and/or Selenium using the Big5/cp950 codepage, rather than Unicode?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get the element by `CLASS_NAME`:

```
nowrap = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'nowrap')
print(nowrap.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the way I have done this in the past is to access the innertext attribute of the element.

So for your code I would do something like:

```
text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//h1[@class="nowrap"]').get_attribute('innerText')
```

Assuming you are finding the element with that XPATH.

Answer (score 0):

```
def lr_parse(text, left, right):
    return str(text).partition(str(left))[-1].partition(str(right))[0]
```

this simple function returns the value between to strings for you're use case do this:

`soho = lr_parse(page, "0.4em;">", "<span ")`

print(soho) = SOHO yaya